# Zend Framework 2 not working on MAMP

Tags: zend-framework2, mamp

has anyone had an error with their zend framework application not running on mamp?. Note that this application is working properly on xampp

I'm encounter 404 messages while navigating on my application

Comment: What have you tried? The default ZF2 tutorial? Something wrong with configuring your vhost for example?

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution here: http://hibbard.eu/php-headerlocation-not-working-in-mamp/
You have to change in php.ini output_buffering = 4096 (instead of off)
On Mac Maverick in MAMP Pro Menu File - Edit Template - php - choose ini for you choosen php version.
To check if this value is really changed, look at output of phpinfo.

Old answer:

Same thing here, the routing is not working with my MAMP setup. I tried a lot already, but have not found a solution yet. My application runs with XAMPP too. If I try to write the settings in have in my httpd.conf file for XAMPP for the virtual host into the the additional parameters for  Field in MAMP PRO apache wont even start. I am now trying to compare the two httpd.conf settings which is quite a task. At first I even looked at the wrong one, the httpd.conf for MAMP PRO is located /Users/yourusername/Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO (Mac Mavericks).

I thought at first it might be a problem with the .htaccess file in the public directory, but I do not think so any more.

Comment: How you found this question?

Comment: I was able to fix my issue. I've adjusted permissions on the apache configuration